# Oracle 12.1.2 wrong cardinality on equal predicate even though I have gathered the latest table stats

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, cardinality

The following example is a smaller version of the query that I am trying to tune as I noticed that the wrongness of the plan emanates on this particular operation.

```
select  count (*) from XVIEWMGR.XV_CASE_STAGES_DATA
where  stage_id = max_initial_or_reopen_id
```

[image]

As mentioned, table stats and corresponding indexes have been recently gathered but no histograms has been created for each column as they are highly distinct. I've even created extended statistics for those to columns to no avail.

```
    OWNER                TABLE_NAME                       NUM_ROWS LAST_ANALYZED      
-------------------- ------------------------------ ---------- -------------------
XVIEWMGR             XV_CASE_STAGES_DATA                314079 09-11-2018 14:29:01


    TABLE_NAME                     COLUMN_NAME                    LAST_ANAL SAMPLE_SIZE  NUM_NULLS NUM_DISTINCT    DENSITY
------------------------------ ------------------------------ --------- ----------- ---------- ------------ ----------
XV_CASE_STAGES_DATA            STAGE_ID                       09-NOV-18      314079          0       308733 .00000323904474
XV_CASE_STAGES_DATA            MAX_INITIAL_OR_REOPEN_ID       09-NOV-18      314079          0       308728 .0000032390972
```

I hope you guys can help.

Comment: I was finding it hard to have the execution plan come out on a much more readable format but will do that next time. the 308K rows on the plan is for the actual rows which you can get using /*+ GATHER_PLAN_STATISTICS  */ hint. Its the "E rows" that showing as 1 which is wrong. This subsequently affects  the rest of the plan in my main query as the optimizer chooses the wrong access paths

Comment: You can try to create an [extended multicolumn statistics](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28274/stats.htm#BEIEEIJA) for both `STAGE_ID` + `MAX_INITIAL_OR_REOPEN_ID` columns, use `create_extended_statistics ` in order to do that. However I am not sure if this will work for comparison of two column, since the documentation shows an example of a condition like `column1=value1 AND column2=value2`. If this will not work, then you may try to use a multicolumn functional index as the last resort.

Comment: Can you check the index statistics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Dynamic statistics](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/tgsql/options-for-optimizer-statistics-gathering.html#GUID-DEE2AF8B-5F4B-4FE7-9F0E-7D188921EBCC) (also known as dynamic sampling) is pretty good at filling in gaps like this.

Test setup:

```
create table xv_case_stages_data
( stage_id integer
, max_initial_or_reopen_id integer );

insert into xv_case_stages_data (stage_id, max_initial_or_reopen_id)
select rownum, rownum
from dual connect by rownum <= 1000;

commit;

call dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user, 'XV_CASE_STAGES_DATA');
```

Test execution plans in 12.2 using [xplanx.sql](http://www.williamrobertson.net/documents/xplanx.html) (some output removed for readability):

```
SQL> select count (*) from xv_case_stages_data where stage_id = max_initial_or_reopen_id

SQL> @xplanx

Plan hash value: 1750917958

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name                | Starts | E-Rows | A-Rows |   A-Time   | Buffers |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |                     |      1 |        |      1 |00:00:00.01 |       7 |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE    |                     |      1 |      1 |      1 |00:00:00.01 |       7 |
|*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| XV_CASE_STAGES_DATA |      1 |      1 |   1000 |00:00:00.01 |       7 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
   2 - filter("STAGE_ID"="MAX_INITIAL_OR_REOPEN_ID")
```

With dynamic sampling at level 4:

```
SQL> select /*+ dynamic_sampling(4) */ count (*) from xv_case_stages_data where stage_id = max_initial_or_reopen_id

SQL> @xplanx

Plan hash value: 1750917958

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name                | Starts | E-Rows | A-Rows |   A-Time   | Buffers |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |                     |      1 |        |      1 |00:00:00.01 |       7 |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE    |                     |      1 |      1 |      1 |00:00:00.01 |       7 |
|*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| XV_CASE_STAGES_DATA |      1 |   1000 |   1000 |00:00:00.01 |       7 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
   2 - filter("STAGE_ID"="MAX_INITIAL_OR_REOPEN_ID")

Note
-----
   - dynamic statistics used: dynamic sampling (level=4)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Dynamic sampling was a solution I was considering but wanted to fix the underlying problem. I'm pretty sure that extended statistics should have fixed it but it may be a bug in the optimizer considering we apply PSU in our environment which does not involve optimizer bug fix. Thanks again

Comment: Good point about fixing the underlying issue. I don’t have an answer, I’m afraid. I did try extended stats (defining a column group) and it made no difference to the estimate.